# Modify Post Status Arguments

Tags: post-status

Is it possible to edit existing registered post statuses?

I am using the Edit Flow plugin to create custom statuses, however, the plugin does not offer the option to set whether the statuses are 'public' or not. I went in to the code and was able to insert that in, but obviously that will get overwritten with any updates. Essentially, I am looking for a complimentary function to add_post_type_support() for post statuses.

So something like

```
add_action('init', 'my_custom_init');
function my_custom_init() {

      add_post_status_support( 'custom_status', array('public'=>true) );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter a post status after init by changing the global variable `$wp_post_statusses`:

```
function alt_post_status() {
    global $wp_post_statuses;

    $wp_post_statuses['custom_status']->public = true;
}

add_action( 'init', 'alt_post_status' );
```

[register_post_status()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/post.php#L0) (line 922) does the same thing:

```
...

global $wp_post_statuses;

if (!is_array($wp_post_statuses))
    $wp_post_statuses = array();

// Args prefixed with an underscore are reserved for internal use.
$defaults = array(
    'label' => false,
    'label_count' => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => null,
    '_builtin' => false,
    'public' => null,
    'internal' => null,
    'protected' => null,
    'private' => null,
    'publicly_queryable' => null,
    'show_in_admin_status_list' => null,
    'show_in_admin_all_list' => null,
);
$args = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);
$args = (object) $args;

...

$wp_post_statuses[$post_status] = $args;

...
```

Comment: Works perfectly, the first part anyway, didn't test the second since the first worked ha